# How do you count your iOS app install base?

Tags: ios, deployment, analytics

At [Flow Pilots](http://www.flowpilots.com/), we'd love to keep track how many people install and use our apps. We make apps for enterprise customers so these apps may be in the AppStore but they may also use enterprise deployment.

How do you count users? Can you track installs / reinstalls / updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this (you should clarify this with your customers if this is ok for them) is to send data to your server. Just keep track of the session count (or even put a single value to your NSUserDefaults) and application version and you should be fine:

- Install: session count is 0, send a "hello" message to your server (server stores [device ID](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5))
- Reinstall: same as "Install" (server recognizes that the device id already exists)
- Update: application version is not the same as on last startup, send a "update" message to your server

Answer (score 5):

For some reason Apple doesn't provide these stats.  I have no idea why as they are probably ***the*** key stats that people want to see.

There are two main ways that I know of obtaining those stats:

1. Log into iTunes connect every week and manually record those stats and add them up yourself. (see [App Store Reporting Instructions](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf))
2. Buy an app (iOS or OSX) that does 1. for you, and will keep track of the total stats.

I've never done #2, but there are several Apps around that do this.

Comment: In the meanwhile Apple provide this information via the itunes connect.

Comment: Where does Apple provide this info itunes connect? I do not see any of those informations. Please note: the question is about currently active installations (how many people have not deleted the app after installation) not install count!